# Will enabling additional features from Google in ReCAPTCHA Enterprise affect the site-verify response?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

Our PROD environment is currently using ReCAPTCHA Enterprise Key + Legacy secret key, which still using "site verify" to verifying the score of the user.

We are planning on migrate to Assessment feature with the additional features (e.g 11 score levels).

[image]

---

So I would like to know that if Google have enabled this feature, will:

1. it affect the “https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify” response?
2. the score in “https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify” also reflect 11 levels?
3. the existing V3 secret key / site key still valid after the feature enabled?

---

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Siteverify is a reCaptcha v3 endpoint which is used for validating whether the response sent by the token from reCaptcha widget is valid or not and can only give a score value ranging from 0 to 1(while 0 seemingly response generated by bot and 1 represents a valid human response). Assessment is an enhancement made to siteverify in the reCaptcha enterprise edition which can be used for more sophisticated behavioral analysis by leveraging various score levels(up to 11). So, even if you have upgraded your reCaptcha to enterprise edition if you are using siteverify endpoint you can only use score levels between 0 to 1.[1][2]

**Migrating from reCaptcha(v2 or v3) to reCaptcha enterprise:**

As mentioned in this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/migrate-recaptcha#:%7E:text=Migrating%20from%20a%20non%2DEnterprise%20version%20of%20reCAPTCHA%20to%20reCAPTCHA%20Enterprise%20involves%20choosing%20an%20active%20site%20key%20from%20the%20reCAPTCHA%20Admin%20console%20and%20migrating%20the%20site%20key.%20You%20can%20migrate%20one%20or%20more%20active%20site%20keys.%20However%2C%20you%20can%20migrate%20only%20one%20site%20key%20at%20a%20time.) on migrating non-Enterprise version of reCaptcha to reCaptcha Enterprise

> Migrating from a non-Enterprise version of reCAPTCHA to reCAPTCHA Enterprise involves choosing an active site key from the reCAPTCHA Admin console and migrating the site key. You can migrate one or more active site keys. However, you can migrate only one site key at a time.

Hence, you can utilize the same keys which you have been using for non-Enterprise reCaptcha in Enterprise version of reCaptcha.

**Will migrating to reCaptcha Enterprise affect the site verify endpoint’s response?**

Migrating to reCaptcha Enterprise won’t affect any features that are available in non-Enterprise reCaptcha like siteverify. It only checks whether the response is valid or not and further investigates the cause of an invalid response.

**References:**

[1] https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#site_verify_response
[2] https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/interpret-assessment-website#interpret_assessment

Comment: Thanks, would the score in V3 site response will also have 11 levels, or will be the same as existing one?

Comment: @JamiePhan if you want to use 11 score levels it is only possible with the assessment feature of reCaptcha Enterprise. The siteverify response in reCaptcha v3 contains only score levels between 0 to 1.

Comment: @JamiePhan have you got time to go through my response, kindly revert back if you still have some queries.